# How do I change the routing in ini file, of Zend framework, to point to another controller?

Tags: zend-framework, url-rewriting

Say if I want to change the router.  If I type example.com/controller1/action1, I want it to go to example.com/controller2/action2  How do I set this up in the ini file?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to access controller2 action2 from the url controller1/action1, then the following should do the trick :

First, create an INI file with the following content (/configs/routes.ini) :

```
[production]
routes.controller1_action1.route = "controller1/action1"
routes.controller1_action1.defaults.controller = "controller2"
routes.controller1_action1.defaults.action = "action2"
```

Then add the following code snippet to your bootstrap :

```
protected function _initRewrite() {
  $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
  $router = $front->getRouter();
  $config = new Zend_Config_Ini(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/routes.ini', 'production');
  $router->addConfig($config,'routes');
}
```

Comment: Do I need to add any PHP code?  This doesn't seem to work, not sure what mistake I am doing

Comment: I updated my answer, adding the things you should change to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on wimvds' post - if applicable, perhaps you also need to specify the module?  Also, I'm not sure if this will make a difference, but I also prefix my routes with 'resources.router'.

So, the full set might be :-

```
resources.router.routes.controller1_action1.route = "controller1/action1"
resources.router.routes.controller1_action1.defaults.controller = "controller2"
resources.router.routes.controller1_action1.defaults.action = "action2"
resources.router.routes.controller1_action1.defaults.module = "module2"
```

Hope that helps.